# List health check endpoints

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller, health-check

I have a Blazor WASM dashboard in which I show every single service status querying my ASP NET Core 8 Rest API.
Every time a new health check is added at the backend side, I need to modify also the frontend configuration to add/remove new/old endpoints.

I need to expose all registered health check endpoints to my frontend avoiding to change its configuration every time.

So the idea is to create a simple controller that returns all available health endpoints that then the frontend can use to query states.

I've tried to inject `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider` to my controller looking on `ActionDescriptors` but the health endpoints, added with default `MapHealthChecks()` method aren't available.

How can I retrieve them?

Comment: There's only one endpoint that returns the status of all health checks. You can [customize the output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-8.0#customize-output) to return the details you want